# Does apt update manually installed packages

Tags: debian, apt

I'm trying to install bnx2 non free driver on Debian wheezy. The driver is in non free repositories. Since there is no network connectivity I should download .deb file and install it on the box. After installing Does `apt` update that package when new versions released or because it is manually installed it ignores it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package will be upgraded if an upgrade cantidate is available. There is no difference between a package that is installed via `apt` and one that is installed directly by dpkg. The state goes to the same database.